# Why am I getting "Method not allowed" using WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest?

Tags: jquery, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass multiple parameters to my wcf service using jquery.

everything works great if the service operation has no/one parameter but I start having "method not allowed" if I add two or more.

I am using GET method because I will allow the service to be consumed from other domain.

any ideas?

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public List<Pair> GetPair(int quantity, string password)
{}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#aService").click(function() {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/FightService.svc/GetPair",
                contentType: "text/plain, charset=utf-8",
                data: "quantity=1&password=somethinghere",
                processData: true,
                success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert("data..." + data);
                    alert("length..." + data.length);
                    alert("thename..." + data[0].TheName);

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });


        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate="GetPair?quantity={quantity}&password={password}")]
```

then call

```
$.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/FightService.svc/GetPair?quantity=1&password=somethinghere",
            contentType: "text/plain, charset=utf-8",
            processData: true,
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                alert("data..." + data);
                alert("length..." + data.length);
                alert("thename..." + data[0].TheName);

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```